# how to replace the next word in a string in pandas based on a conditional word appearing before that word

Tags: python, regex, pandas, numpy, replace

I have a dataframe that looks like the following but with more rows and varieties of strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
               'B': ['a is nice', 'b is house', 'c is good', 'd is huge', 'e is friendly']})
```

I would like to replace the next word in a string with 'was' if that string contains the letter 'b'.
so, 'b is a house' --> 'b was a house'

I know how to use np.where, or df.replace to replace the same word but I am not sure how I can change the next word after 'b'.

```
 df.B = np.where(df.B.str.contains('b', regex=False), 'was', df.B)

 df.B = df.B.str.replace(r'b', 'was')
```

thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
df.apply(lambda x: re.sub('b\s+[a-zA-Z]+','b was',x['B']),axis=1)
```

Alternatively, using replace:

```
df['B']=df.B.str.replace('b\s+[a-zA-Z]+', 'b was')
```

Comment: you example only works if he wants to replace `'is'` for `'was'`.

Comment: thank you for your reply. the problem with my dataset is that the next word is not always is, this was just as example. it is a huge dataset and I want a way to replace the next word after 'b', no matter what that word is

Comment: Sorry my bad..Updated my answer now..let me know if this works

Comment: thank you very much, it indeed works. However, do you know if there is a way of doing it with df.replace or np.where, something like df.replace( 'original_word' +1 , 'replacement_word'), with 1 indicating the next word. I know it sends an error because 1 is not str, but do you know if there is a way of indicating that? thank you very much

Comment: Please check the alternate solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about data format in your **column B**. My assumption is: word 'b' or any word in your condition is a starting word, otherwise you need to change condition in the function (replace_next). Take a look at this:

```
def replace_next(row_string, search_word, target):
    if(row_string.startswith(search_word)):
        words = row_string.split()
        to_replace = words[words.index(search_word) + 1]
        return row_string.replace(to_replace, target)
    else:
        return row_string
```

Then call that on your dataframe:

```
df.apply(lambda x : replace_next(x['B'], 'e', 'was'), axis=1)
```

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. since you mentioned if 'b' is not the fisrt word, am I right to think that I should replace str.startswith with str.find for the code to word. thank you

Comment: @lulumirzai You can change it to any condition that fits your need, as long as it valuates to boolean.
However I should mention that if your B columns has string such `a is humble` and your search_word is 'b', using str.find will return the index of 'b' (meaning 'b' exists) but the function above will throw an error. So, customize the function based on your data. Please reply if you need further details. :)

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. i will keep that in mind